# Suggested video settings for progressive download. (android)

Tags: android

My app uses streaming (i think the correct term is progressive download) for videos. To be able to do that, the mp4 file must be hinted and I manage to do that. Now, is there a suggested or advisable settings for the mp4 like the bit rates, resolution, frame rate etc so that the playback is smooth?

Answer (score 1):

That's device-specific. Can you predict what devices will use 90% of your users?

Safe (minimal) resolution for Android devices is 320x400 with minimal framerate 15fps.
Maybe 25fps will be also ok.

You'd better get a cheapest (=slowest) android device, like HTC Tattoo, and check all your settings yourself.

You can also try with Android emulator, but its speed depends on your PC, it may be a lot faster or a lot slower than most of Android devices, so, no guarantees.